# Get second last key value .net C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to be able to get out a value from a string.

Essentially I always have something like:

"1_1,5,8215,886,1142,1,7,64"

I need to know what the second last number is, i.e. the 7. 
Note that the 7 can be 1 or more digits....

Thanks in advance!

C#, .net 3.5

Comment: string.Split, an array index, and int.Parse would be tempting .. make sure to check/handle failure conditions.

Comment: Should add flag for homework?

Comment: could also do a search for commas from the back, if that is indeed the definitive separator. might be more efficient than splitting the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string numbers = "1_1,5,8215,886,1142,1,7,64";
string[] items = numbers.Split(',');
string item = items[items.Length - 2];
```

Comment: this is very very inefficient!U r using a complete array to store data which is of no use!

Comment: Technical does what I needed it to. Thanks.

Comment: @Anirudha, the guy is obviously a student or something.. what he needs is the job to be done in the simplest and easiest way for him to understand.. no need to complicate things. :)

Comment: @Anirudha - If he's running the code on a PDP-11 then I agree with you, but modern computers wouldn't break a sweat doing this trivial computation. Matt's solution is very straightforward and maintainable.

Comment: @Enigmativity Just compared **above** method with the `regex` method on `10000` numbers separated by `,`.Guess what there was **no difference** between them.`Regex` ran only `1` to `2` ms faster than above method.You were right!

Comment: @Anirudha - that's the power of modern CPUs for you. Don't get fooled when Dell asks if you'd like to upgrade your CPU when you buy a new computer from them. Unless you're playing games or doing some sort of signal processing just get more memory instead. :-)

Comment: I'm sure a more efficient solution exists, (e.g. maybe backward loop, checking for the second `','`) but unless you plan on running this through thousands to millions of lines, it's probably not worth your trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "1_1,5,8215,886,1142,1,7,64";
string[] arr = s.Split(',');

int myValue = Convert.ToInt32(arr[arr.Count - 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var shortenedString =s.Substring(0,s.LastIndexOf(','));
var intString = shortenedString.Substring(shortenedString.LastIndexIf(',', shortenedString.Length)); 
var number = Convert.ToInt32(intString);
```

Can be easily updated to find any required number without string split. Shall be more efficient than splitting